# Eclipse - can you navigate to an injected bean

Tags: eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using the STS eclipse IDE version 2.8

Is it possible to navigate directly to a class from the bean name ?
IE to the class whose bean name is 'foo.bar in the example below:

```
public class SomeClass() {

  @Autowired(required=true)
  @Qualifier("foo.bar")
  private FooServive myFooService;

  ...
}
```

I know I can get to it from the Spring Explorer tab but I want to miss out the middle man.

Comment: naah - F3 does not work. F3 appears just to work with Java class names

Comment: I can try hook your cursor on foo.bar with <kbd>ctrl</kdb> clicked, and see if it change to a link.

Answer (score 3):

...often, also the "Spring Beans references search" is quite helpful. It provides an overview of all *references* to the given bean name; typically you'll get the class definition, the XML definition and uses in dependency injection.

Standard keybinding for this is CTRL-SHIFT-g.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Alt-F7` to Java-search on `"foo.bar"`. It will bring up the bean definition so named (at least when using XML configuration files). At the bean definition you can press `F3` on the value of the `class` attribute, which will bring you to the class definition itself. You have to have the *Spring Nature* enabled of course.

Comment: Odd. I guess I knew that. However when I search for the foo.bar my eclipse finds no occurrences. I can search for anything else with success.

Comment: @BillComer You might have to add your config files to the Spring beans registry under Spring menu entry of the project preferences (only visible when The _Spring Nature_ is enabled)